# php empty values

Tags: php

I have a problem with my php script it is...

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR, expecting ')' in C:\wamp\www\register.php on line 34
```

I am a nube with !Empty so let me know if im doing something wrong.

```
if (!empty($username or $email or $password or $repassword)) 
{

}
else
{

}
```

This is my code but something in the middle of the else and if statement

So what am i doing wrong?

My question is what am i doing wrong?
oh and

- $username
- $email
- $password
- $repassword

are all values

and yes this is a script to figure out if someone has filled in all of the textboxes in the form for a register script.

Comment: this will fail if the user tries to use `0000000000000000` as his password ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want something along these lines...

```
if (!empty($username) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($repassword)) 
{
    // none of the values are empty
}
else
{
    // at least one of the values is empty
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation Section](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) says

> empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse
>   error. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)).

Answer (score 3):

[`empty`](http://php.net/empty) is only able to check a variable for its emptiness. `$username or $email or …` is a boolean expression which either evaluates to TRUE or FALSE – not what you want. you have to use multiple `empty` calls:

```
if (!(empty($username) or empty($email) or empty($password) or empty($repassword))) {
  // all set!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) will check whether or not a variable which is passed as its argument is considered to be empty, which means it will check whether or not its argument contains -

1. "" (an empty string)
2. 0 (0 as an integer)
3. 0.0 (0 as a float)
4. "0" (0 as a string)
5. NULL
6. FALSE
7. array() (an empty array)
8. var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

In your code, you are providing `$username or $email or $password or $repassword` as its argument. This is a boolean expression, meaning it will evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. So the argument to `empty()` will be a boolean value, not a variable. This is the reason why you are getting this error.

I am assuming that you want to check whether or not all of these variables are empty. If this is the case, then you can do this in the following way -

```
if( !empty($username) or 
    !empty($email) or 
    !empty($password) or 
    !empty($repassword))
{
    ..........
}
else
{
    ........
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the OR operator for calling a function multiple times with multiple variables.

If you want to make sure that all variables are not empty, use this:

```
if ( ! (empty($username) ||  
        empty($email)    ||
        empty($password) || 
        empty($repassword)
       )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty only works on variables

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

The expression x or y or z will be evaluated and therefore will not be a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because `empty()` can only check a single variable.

Even if it did work, you are doing it wrong, this if statement would check if any of the four variables is not empty. Therefore - if it was valid code - it would return true even if only one variable was defined.

So change it to this:

```
if (!empty($username) and !empty($email) and !empty($password) and !empty($repassword))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple OR's in one empty function. Your code will have to be like this:

```
if (!empty($strValue1) OR !empty($strValue2) OR !empty($strValue3)) {
   // code
} else {
   // other code
}
```